# How Do I Make A Line Graph Using User Input To A JTextFiled

Tags: java

I have a program that allows the user to enter their household spending and income into a JTextField and the amount appears as an updated current Amount at the top of the frame so for example if they had £500 and wanted to add £100 they would enter it into a textfild hit submit and it would update the JLabel to current amount £600

I want to be able to allow the user to click a button and for it to show a graph of their income and outcome for their household. So the line graph will get higher and lower depending on what their current Amount is and would show the history for the previous 20 or so transactions how can I do This Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

There is no "easy" way how to print a graph.

You have to look for some library which is able to do it and follow the tutorial how put data into that graph and how to draw it.

Google -> Java Line Graph